# Finagling the space and width arguments to barplot to align 2x1 plot window

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'd like to align the bottom `barplot` in the following so that the *groups* line up vertically between the two plots:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
n = 1:5
barplot(-2:2, width = n, space = .2)

barplot(matrix(-10:9, nrow = 4L, ncol = 5L), beside = TRUE,
        width = rep(n/4, each = 5L), space = c(0, .8))
```

[image: Two bar plots stacked vertically. Each shows 5 "groups" of bars -- in the top plot, each "group" is just a single bar, but in the bottom plot, each group is 4 bars. Since these groups correspond, we might expect them to align vertically across the two plots, but this is not the case.]

I've been staring at the definition of the `space` and `width` arguments to `barplot` (from `?barplot`) for a while and I really expected the above to work (but clearly it didn't):

> `width`   -- optional vector of bar widths. Re-cycled to length the number of bars drawn. Specifying a single value will have no visible effect...
>
> `space`   -- the amount of space (as a fraction of the average bar width) left before each bar. May be given as a single number or one number per bar. If `height` is a matrix and `beside` is `TRUE`, `space` may be specified by two numbers, where the first is the space between bars in the same group, and the second the space between the groups. If not given explicitly, it defaults to `c(0,1)` if `height` is a matrix and `beside` is `TRUE`, and to `0.2` otherwise.

As I read it, this means we should be able to match the group widths in the top plot by dividing each group into 4 (hence `n/4`). For `space`, since we're dividing each bar's width by 4, the average width will as well; hence we should multiply the fraction by 4 to compensate for this (hence `space = c(0, 4*.2)`).

However it appears this is being ignored. In fact, it seems all the boxes have the same width! In tinkering around, I've only been able to get the relative *within-group* widths to vary.

Will it be possible to accomplish what I've got in mind with `barplot`? If not, can someone say how to do this in e.g. `ggplot2`?

Comment: if i find time i'll dive into the source of `barplot`, i have a feeling the documentation is lying...

Comment: It seems like you only can have one `width` per row for the input matrix. `width` seems to use `nrow` values of the `width` vector, which are then recycled. The rest of the values are discarded. Start here: `barplot(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3L, ncol = 2L), beside = TRUE)`. Add `width` values, one per row: `barplot(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3L, ncol = 2L), beside = TRUE, width = c(1:3))` - recycled across columns (groups). Try with one `width` value per element (as you did): `barplot(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3L, ncol = 2L), beside = TRUE, width = c(1:3, 3:1))`. Nope, only the three first (`nrow`) are used.

Comment: ...This recycling (and discard) rule means that to be able to create column specific `width`s, the data needs to be reshaped, so that a `width` can be assigned to each element, as nicely described by @Len. (just needed to clarify my previous (now deleted) a bit sloppy comment... ;) )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to do this with base plot as well, but it helps to pass the matrix as a vector for the second plot. Subsequently, you need to realize the space argument is a fraction of the average bar width. I did it as follows:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
widthsbarplot1 <- 1:5
spacesbarplot1 <- c(0, rep(.2, 4))

barplot(-2:2, width = widthsbarplot1, space = spacesbarplot1)

widthsbarplot2 <- rep(widthsbarplot1/4, each = 4)
spacesbetweengroupsbarplot2 <- mean(widthsbarplot2)

allspacesbarplot2 <- c(rep(0,4), rep(c(spacesbetweengroupsbarplot2, rep(0,3)), 4))

matrix2 <- matrix(-10:9, nrow = 4L, ncol = 5L)

barplot(c(matrix2),
    width = widthsbarplot2,
    space = allspacesbarplot2,
    col = c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue"))
```

[image: Base plot]

Comment: Smart thinking! Just splay the matrix into a vector and fake the spacing... I need more sleep... i made a few edits to simplify the code a bit, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: No problem, it is more readable now indeed! And I hope this helps to get the desired plot of your real data as well. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can actually pass widths in ggplot as vectors as well. You'll need the dev version of ggplot2 to get the correct dodging though:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(n = 1:5, y = -2:2)
df1$x <- cumsum(df1$n)
df2 <- data.frame(n = rep(1:5, each = 4), y2 = -10:9)
df2$id <- 1:4                                                    # just for the colors

df3 <- full_join(df1, df2)

p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_col(width = df1$n, col = 1)
p2 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x, y2, group = y2, fill = factor(id))) + 
  geom_col(width = df3$n, position = 'dodge2', col = 1) +
  scale_fill_grey(guide = 'none')

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1, align = 'v')
```

[image]

Comment: Fixed now for 0 bars.

Answer (score 6):

Another way, using only `base R` and still using `barplot` (not going "down" to `rect`) is to do it in several `barplot` calls, with `add=TRUE`, playing with `space` to put the groups of bars at the right place.

As already highlighted, the problem is that `space` is proportional to the mean of `width`. So you need to correct for that.

Here is my way:

```
# draw first barplot, getting back the value
bp <- barplot(-2:2, width = n, space = .2)

# get the xlim
x_rg <- par("usr")[1:2]

# plot the "frame"
plot(0, 0, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", xlim=x_rg, xaxs="i", ylim=range(as.vector(pr_bp2)))

# plot the groups of bars, one at a time, specifying space, with a correction according to width, so that each group start where it should
sapply(1:5, function(i) barplot(pr_bp2[, i, drop=FALSE], beside = TRUE, width = n[i]/4, space = c((bp[i, 1]-n[i]/2)/(n[i]/4), rep(0, 3)), add=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: This also facilitates the following bells and whistles for adorning a similar plot further -- (1) if adding `arrows` and you'd like them to have different lengths for each group (to match the different bar widths), it's much easier in this loop (2) if each group should have a different within-group color scheme, it's trivial in separate `barplot` calls ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840378)) (3) if you'd like to have different `cex.names` under each group (again to match the widths), it's trivial in separate `barplot` calls

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in ggplot2 by setting the x-axis locations of the bars explicitly and using `geom_rect` for plotting. Here's an example that's probably more complicated than it needs to be, but hopefully it will demonstrate the basic idea:

```
library(tidyverse)

sp = 0.4

d1 = data.frame(value=-2:2) %>% 
  mutate(key=paste0("V", 1:n()),
         width=1:n(),
         spacer = cumsum(rep(sp, n())) - sp,
         xpos = cumsum(width) - 0.5*width + spacer)

d2 = matrix(-10:9, nrow = 4L, ncol = 5L) %>% 
  as.tibble %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>%
  mutate(width = as.numeric(gsub("V","",key))) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(width = width/n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(spacer = rep(cumsum(rep(sp, length(unique(key)))) - sp, each=4),
         xpos = cumsum(width) - 0.5*width + spacer)

d = bind_rows(list(d1=d1, d2=d2), .id='source') %>% 
  group_by(source, key) %>% 
  mutate(group = LETTERS[1:n()])

ggplot(d, aes(fill=group, colour=group)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=xpos-0.5*width, xmax=xpos+0.5*width, ymin=0, ymax=value)) +
  facet_grid(source ~ ., scales="free_y") +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill=FALSE, colour=FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = d1$xpos, labels=d1$key)
```

[image]

Comment: i was hoping a `ggplot` solution would be more concise  will take a closer look in a bit... for base, I know the (ultimate) backup would be to just build the plot with `rect` but i'd rather not go full tedium

Comment: Well, it's late. Maybe I'll wake up in morning with a more elegant answer!

Comment: To be fair, most of that code is to construct the data frame :)